# sed command to replace a value in a file not using find and replace

Tags: sed

I have a file with a string log.txt and inside the file i have multiple lines

```
line 1 text
line2/random/string/version:0.0.30
line 3 randome stuff
http://someurl:8550/
```

So currently I use `sed` to find and replace 0.0.30 to a new value like 0.0.31
with

```
sed -i s/0.0.30/0.0.31/g log.txt
```

The problem with this is I need to know the previous value.

Is there a way to always remove 0.0.30 from the string in the file and replace it with a new value ?

Maybe a indexof or a substring.

Comment: Clearly your sample input is not representative enough and answerers can only guess an solution that will work for that simple input, but will fail in your real input.

Comment: sorry my mistake added some more data

Comment: How does Inian's answer fail on that input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex definition to match `0.0.30` and replace it with `0.0.31` as below. The `--posix` flag is to ensure no GNU dialects are applied and plain BRE (Basic Regular Expressions) library is used. Since `\{2\}` is a BRE syntax to match 2 occurrences of the digit.

```
sed -i --posix 's/[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\{2\}/0.0.31/' file
```

See explanation for regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/6m83lw/1).

Comment: I have tested the above problem is its also replacing 0.0.31 where other numbers are in the file if that makes sense

Comment: @Flenters: You haven't clearly explained that. So you have multiple patterns like that, and in every pattern, replace the last digit by 1?

Comment: `sed -i --posix 's/[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\{2\}/0.0.31/' file` better, not?

Comment: that is perfect. would you mind explaining the expression so that i can learn. so i take it [[:digit:]] is the numerical digit. What does the \ do and at the end \{2\} ?

Comment: @Quasímodo: Agreed. Edited the answer the `\(..\)` were redundant here.

Comment: @Flenters: Open the hyperlink I've posted for the regex explanation. Understand how the regex library parses the definition.